# Detect dplyr subtable as function instead of table

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny app and I want to show some metrics in the main page of my dashboard.

I have a table with products and the columns are: row_names(works as ID), name(name of the product).

In some part of the code I do a dplyr query within a reactive function where I want to filter the table by the Product choosen by the user on a scroll down menu on the sideBar of my app. I am able to do this scroll down menu but when I do my query and run the app it says: Error:could not find function 'res', I dont understand because res should be the table filtered its not a function.

I can provide the UI part if needed but I think its okay

```
# Use purrr's split() and map() function to create the list
# needed to display the name of the product but pass its
# row_name code as the value
products_list <- products %>%

  collect() %>%

  split(.$name) %>%

  map(~ .$row_names)

# UI part here but I think its not relevant  

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  tab_list <- NULL

  base_products <- reactive({

    res <- products %>%

      filter(row_names == input$product) %>%

    res

  })

output$total_products <- renderValueBox({

    # The following code runs inside the database.

    # pull() bring the results into R, which then

    # it's piped directly to a valueBox()

    base_products() %>%

      tally() %>%

      pull() %>%

      as.integer() %>%

      valueBox(subtitle = "Number of Products")

  })
```

Main inspiration comes from this link:
https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/dashboards/

Comment: You have an extra pipe at `filter(row_names == input$product) %>%`

Comment: ... feel so stupid. THANK YOU!